# Getting exception while executing mule batch flow like unable to delete file in object store by mentioning the path of the file

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

Am getting exception like this

```
Message               : Deleting D:\Mule-Soft\Mule-3.9-labdocs-workspace\lab-docs-pdfs-workspace\mule-way2learn-ws\.mule\.mule\batch-job-demo\objectstore\f59294d0-1133-11ea-af5c-ba4720524153\f8e14aa0-1133-11ea-af5c-ba4720524153.obj failed
Payload               : [{updated_date=null, user_name=test1, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=test1, created_by=admin, first_name=test1, id=100}, {updated_date=null, user_name=test2, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=test2, created_by=admin, first_name=test2, id=101}, {updated_date=null, user_name=test3, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=test3, created_by=admin, first_name=test3, id=102}, {updated_date=null, user_name=test4, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=test4, created_by=admin, first_name=test4, id=103}, {updated_date=null, user_name=test5, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=test5, created_by=admin, first_name=test5, id=104}, {updated_date=null, user_name=af, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=af, created_by=admin, first_name=af, id=105}, {updated_date=null, user_name=bf, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=bf, created_by=admin, first_name=bf, id=106}, {updated_date=null, user_name=aaaa, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=aaaa, created_by=admin, first_name=aaa, id=107}, {updated_date=null, user_name=cccc, created_date=2014-12-11, status=10, updated_by=null, last_name=ccc, created_by=admin, first_name=ccc, id=109}]
Payload Type          : java.util.LinkedList
Element               : /start-batch-job/processors/0 @ batch-job-demo:batch-job-demo.xml:74 (users-accounts-batch-job)
Element XML           : <batch:execute name="users-accounts-batch-job" doc:name="users-accounts-batch-job"></batch:execute>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreException: Deleting D:\Mule-Soft\Mule-3.9-labdocs-workspace\lab-docs-pdfs-workspace\mule-way2learn-ws\.mule\.mule\batch-job-demo\objectstore\f59294d0-1133-11ea-af5c-ba4720524153\f8e14aa0-1133-11ea-af5c-ba4720524153.obj failed
```

when executing batch job. Shown in the picture. The flow is invoked by http component which calls the flow "user-accounts-batch-job" through batch execute component and then flow continues through "get-user-account-step" and again batch execute calls "get-user-records-flow"  then flow continues to second batch step and second batch step calls "get-account-record" then flow reaches to on complete phase. what's happening is after querying the database in "get-user-records" mule is throwing the error mentioned above I don't understand how to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears to be caused by this bug: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-17349

If you are a MuleSoft customer you can ask for a patch for it on MuleSoft's Help Center. I'm not aware of any workarounds for it.